# Determine which tags within xpath string have a class

Tags: r, xpath

**My data:**

```
  xpath <- "/html/body[@class=\"das\"]/div/div[@class=\"ddd\"]/div[@class=\"spasd\"]/div[@class=\"josner(m/doandel\"]/p[@class=\"ficp\"]/a/strong[@class=\"asd\"]"
```

**Question:**

How can i determine which tags within my string `xpath` have a class?

**Expected Output:**

```
c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

**What i tried:**

```
  # Try1: Split on / fails if / is present within class name
  xpath %>% strsplit(split = "/") %>% .[[1]]
  
  # Try2:
  xp <- (strsplit(xpath, split = "")[[1]][-1]) %>% paste(collapse = "")
  rr <- strsplit(xp, split = "\\[(?:.*?)\\]/")[[1]] %>% stringr::str_count(pattern = "/")
  has_class <- lapply(rr, function(r) rep(!r, r + 1)) %>% unlist
```

Edit:

Now that i think of: If i have the related document i can parse the target tag and "go up the tree" and check for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer:

If i have the related document i can parse the target tag and "go up the tree" and check for classes.

```
  classes <- c()
  node <- html_nodes(doc, xpath = xpath)[1]
  name <- "x"
  while(name != "html"){
    classes <- c(classes, node %>% html_attr(name = "class"))
    node %<>% html_nodes(xpath = "..")
    name <- html_name(node)
  }
  classes <- c(classes, node %>% html_attr(name = "class")) %>% rev
  has_classes <- classes %>% is.na %>% magrittr::not()
```